# Server doesn't wait for client to write data on socket in C

Tags: c, sockets

I am currently building a server/client application in C. I am on assignment, so I can't share <del>any</del> much code, but I hope you can help me out and shed some light on my issue anyway.

Assume server is running and accepts connections from multiple clients. As soon the client successfully establishes the connection, it asks the user which action to perform -- let's call them `ACTION 1` and `ACTION 2` and suppose the user selects the first and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> -- so the client writes on the socket a code which represents the user made choice and the server reads it from the socket and sends back a code to let the client know that it is ok.

The next step is to collect the data from the user and send it to the server. Ideally this would happen in this order:

1. the client asks the user for the input;
2. the client writes the data on the socket;
3. the server reads from the socket the data;
4. the server performs the action using the provided data;
5. the sever sends a feedback.

What happens is while (1) is still ongoing, the server reads from (what I believe is) empty socket and doesn't wait for the client to write and send data. So (3) occurs and the server obviously crashes. How do I make the server wait for data before performing whatever it needs to do?

#### Server Side

```
void *deal_with_user(void *arg)
{
    int action = 0;
    int status = 0;

    ConnectingUser* user = (ConnectingUser *) arg;

    action = request_action(user);

    if (action == ACTION_1)
    {
        if ((status = perform_action(user)) != ACTION_GRANTED)
        {
            pthread_exit((void *) 0);
        }
    }
    else if (action == ACTION_2)
    {
        // do nothing yet
    }
    else
    {
        pthread_exit((void *) 0);
    }


    /*
    *
    *   More code...
    *
    */

    pthread_exit((void *) 0);
}

int request_action(ConnectingUser *user)
{
    int status = 0;

    while (!status)
    {
        status = read_user_action(user);

        /*
        *
        * Error Handling code
        *
        */

    return status;
}

int read_user_action(ConnectingUser *user)
{
    int read_bytes;
    int status;
    char *action_code;

    read_bytes = 0;
    action_code = (char *) calloc (4, sizeof(char));

    if ((read_bytes = read(user->user_socket_descriptor, action_code, 4)) <= 0)
    {
        if (read_bytes < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error read_user_action()\n");
            status = READ_ACTION_ERR;
        }
        else if (read_bytes == 0)
        {
            status = BROKEN_PIPE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (write(user->user_socket_descriptor, "OKCODE", 6) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error read_user_action()\n");
            free(action_code);
            return WRITE_ACTION_ERR;
        }

        // get_action() returns either ACTION_1 or ACTION_2
        status = get_action(action_code);
    }

    free(action_code);
    return status;
}

int perform_action(ConnectingUser *user)
{
    int status = 0;

    while (!status)
    {
        status = authorize_action(user);

        /*
        *
        * Error Handling code
        *
        */

    return status;
}

int authorize_action(ConnectingUser *user) 
{
    int read_bytes;
    int status;
    char *action_data;
    NeededData *client_data = NULL;


    read_bytes = 0;
    action_data = (char *) malloc (MAX_LENGTH*sizeof(char));

    if ((read_bytes = read(user->user_socket_descriptor, action_data, MAX_LENGTH)) <= 0)
    {
        if (read_bytes < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error authorize_action()\n");
            free(action_data);
            return READ_DATA_ERR;
        }
        else if (read_bytes == 0)
        {
            free(action_data);
            return BROKEN_PIPE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("I have read something: %s\n", action_data);
    }


    if (checks_out(user, user_list, client_data))
    {
        if (write(user->user_socket_descriptor, "OK-ACT", 6) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Errore authorize_login(): impossibile inviare auth\n");
            free(action_data);
            free(client_data);
            return WRITE_INFO_ERR;
        }
        status = ACTION_GRANTED;
    }
    else
    {
        if (write(user->user_socket_descriptor, "NO-ACT", 6) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Errore authorize_login(): impossibile inviare auth\n");
            free(action_data);
            free(client_data);
            return WRITE_INFO_ERR;
        }
        status = INCORRECT_ACTION;
    }

    free(action_data);
    free(client_data);

    return status;
}
```

#### Client side

```
int ask_for_action()
{
    int action = 0;
    int status = 0;
    char *input;

    input = (char *) calloc(2, sizeof(char));


    while (!status)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Pick action\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "[1] Action One\n[2] Action Two\n\nInput: ");
        fgets(input, 2, stdin);
        getchar();

           /*
            *
            * Error Handling code
            *
            */

            action = write_action(action);
            status = action_one();

           /*
            *
            * Error Handling code
            *
            */
        }
    }

    free(input);
    return action;
}
int write_action(const int action)
{
    int read_chars;
    char *action_code;
    char *server_ans;

       /*
        *
        *  More code
        *
        */

    // Stores the action code
    action_code = (char *) calloc (4, sizeof(char));
    // Stores server response
    server_ans = (char *) calloc (6, sizeof(char));

    if (write(socket_descriptor, action_code, sizeof(action_code)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore write_action()\n");
        free(action_code);
        return WRITE_ACTION_ERR;
    }

    free(action_code);

    if ((read_chars = read(socket_descriptor, server_ans, 6)) <= 0)
    {
       /*
        *
        *  Error Handling
        *
        */
    }

    if (strncmp(server_ans, "OK-ACT", 6) == 0)
    {
        if (cc.debug)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "Action sent correctly.\n");
        }

        free(server_ans);
        return action;
    }

    // Code...
}

int action_one()
{
   // Server should wait for this function to gather input from user, but by
   // the time this is called, the server has moved on and crashed.
}
```

#### Edit 1

I have discovered after the client sends the action code, the server reads 3 bytes --- not printed out on screen, they are `\0` or `\n`, I guess --- before crashing. I have tried flushing the input, but it doesn't get rid of those bytes and keeps on reading them.

Comment: This could use more details. Even though you can't share the effective code, you should try putting a few snippets containing the key aspects of the server (accepting client connections and receiving the data from the socket).

Comment: Take a look at `select` system call (assuming you are running this in unix/linux) . There are plenty of examples, google for select system call

Comment: Assuming you haven't set your sockets to use non-blocking I/O, the recv() call should block until some data is received from the client.  Note that it is not guaranteed to block until all the data is received, so you may need to call it in a loop until you have received all the bytes you expected to get.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I can confirm the sockets do not use non-blocking I/O, I tried to use recv() and the issue is still there. I did not check for the size, though, mostly because user input may vary and therefore also the amount of bytes.

Comment: What value is recv() returning?  If the return value is negative, what is errno set to?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner recv() receives some data. If wrapped in if statement, it reads the empty string, if wrapped in a while it reads the string sent from the client, but it gets stuck in the loop.

Comment: recv is not guaranteed to get any particular number of bytes. If your client sends 100 bytes in a request, then 200 more in another request, recv can get 90, 20, 190 - and it's a completely valid result. Design your code accordingly.